# Loop Not Printing Multiple Rows (C, VS Code)

Tags: c, cs50

I'm new to programming, and I would like to run a program that takes a message (string) and converts it.

The outcome should be that each character (ASCII) within the string is represented as a series of eight 0's and 1's (binary). Each row should represent one character.

I have developed some code which I was hoping would output multiple rows of eight bits, with the number of rows being dependent on the string length of the input message. However, my program only outputs one single row representing only the first character of the input message (and not the rest of the characters). I have tried making nested loops before, using the format:

```
int main(void)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
        {
            printf("F");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 1;
}
```

which outputs:

```
FFFFF
FFFFF
FFFFF
```

However, my current code is:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string message = get_string("Enter your message:\n");
    for (int r = 0; r<strlen(message); r++) // rows (not printing other rows??)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x<8; x++) // // columns: iterate through each character
        {
            int half = (message[r] / 2);
            int remainder = (message[r] % 2);
            if (remainder == 0)
            {
                printf("0");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("1");
            }
            message[r] = half;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

and when I input the message "HI!", my output is:
**00010010**

I know this is the wrong way around for binary, I'm still trying to figure out how to reverse the order.

Only one row is outputted, despite inputting a string with three characters. I have tried adding another loop (as I thought I might need a separate row loop from int r, as int r is used to iterate through the string), and this did not work.

I also tried running the CS50 debugger, which stops at the printf("\n"); line, and int r never increases above 0.

Comment: What are `convert()` and `print_bulb()`?

Comment: It is doubful whether that is your exact code. You've deleted the strange `message[d] = a` (where `a` and `d` were undefined) which might have changed the length of the string, which you obtain on each iteration.

Comment: Your code does compile. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Note that you outputting the binary value in reverse order from convention. The posted `00010010` reverses to `01001000` which is ASCII value of `'H' 0x48`.

Comment: what's `m`? What's `a`?

Comment: Sorry, I had included errors in my code as I changed the names of the parameters to make it more clear (m was the original int r and a was int half)

Comment: `if (r == 0)` That should be `if (remainder == 0)`

Comment: after the first time thru your inner loop, `half` is 0, so `message[r] = half` is `message[0] = 0`'. Next time around the outer loop, that means `strlen(message)==0`, so `1<0` fails, the program terminates. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/fv3oY11br). Not sure what you want to do to fix.. you can 1) capture `strlen(message)` once before the loops begin and use that, 2) don't modify `message`, 3) restore `message` from a temp ..

Comment: @yano thanks so much for your comment, I think this answers my question! :D

Comment: Don't use `strlen(message)` in your loop condition. Use `for (int r = 0; message[r]; r++) ` -- that's what the nul-terminating character is for.

Comment: Here is another approach you can take converting each character to 8-bit binary. [ASCII char to binary](https://paste.opensuse.org/3914fb76033a) (link expires May 12, 2023)

Comment: @Sharyn Glad to help, let me know if you have any questions about the approach. It's pretty straight-forward, but the code is a bit compact which may lead to a question or two.